# How to filter documents with multiple departments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, datatables

I have made a table which lists down the data of the documents with `DataTables`. I manage to get the checkbox working for the document type but not the departments. This might be a little hard for me but I have an idea how to filter by department.

I've thought of converting the departments into an array and split it, then cross check the checked boxes. So far I've got no luck in succeeding.

[This is what I tried so far.](https://codepen.io/reonLOW/pen/oNNgMXv)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

Create a variable to hold the array data from the ajax call in your datatable.

Create two functions (one for the document and the department) for the onchange of these checkboxes (use a class say, checkbox-document and checkbox-department). The sole purpose of these functions is to manipulate the variable above from the ajax call and draw them on the datatable on consequent changes. In this way, your datatable is loosely coupled with the filtering mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. Add `value` to the very department checkbox;
2. Remove `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(arguments){...})` function
3. Change last portion of the code:

   ```
   var table = $("#document-table").DataTable();

   $("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
     if(this.value === 'All'){
       table.search('').draw();
     } else {
       table.search( this.value ).draw();      
     }
   });
   ```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Have you found another solution?